# URL hacking a report to pass a Date Literal filter value vs an actual date

Tags: reporting, date, urlhacking

Though not well documented by Salesforce, it's a well known fact that record pages and saved reports can be dynamically altered by passing URL parameters. For example, with a tabular report whose first filter is "Account Name", you can pass the filter value via a modified URL, like so:

```
/(reportSFID)?pv0=(Account Name)
```

to load the report on that specific account.

My question is in regard to filters on Date values. When I pass a specific date to a date filter value, eg '1/1/2014', it works fine. BUT, when I attempt to pass a date literal, eg 'LAST FISCAL QUARTER', it just takes me to the edit page of the report (which seems to indicate a failure with passing the value).

Has anyone had any experience passing date literal values using dynamic URLs?

---

EDIT: A little more messing around and I discovered a couple things:

- Certain Date Literals CAN be passed - if they are multiple words you need to use underscores in the URL. For example,

`/(reportSFID)?pv0=LAST_MONTH`

- Date literals that specify numerical ranges still don't seem to work, eg "LAST_6_MONTHS". Any insight on whether its possible to use these types of date literals is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it's looking for SOQL date literals, such as LAST_N_MONTHS:6.

Comment: That's it! If you'd like, post it as an answer and I'll choose it.

Comment: Simply an educated guess. I wasn't sure, and didn't have a way to test when I posted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SOQL date literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), such as LAST_N_MONTHS:6 or LAST_N_DAYS:90.